# Maven and dependency:sources goals: use alternate repository to download sources?

Tags: java, maven-3, nexus

I am working with an enterprise Nexus repository, whose contents is rather static, meaning it is not a copy of *central*, but a snapshot at some time.

This Nexus repository does not contains sources classifier. Hence, when I launch one of those goals:

```
mvn dependency:sources
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

I've got a lot, if not all, of dependencies without sources.

What I want to do is pretty simple: I want to tell `dependency` and `eclipse` plugins that they should use the *central* repository only when looking for sources.

If that possible natively?

Can I do that with Nexus and how ?

Comment: Usually you would configure Nexus to proxy central (etc) so that it would go to central and fetch any dependency it doesn't have already, including any with sources classifier. Having Nexus being a temporal, non-updated snapshot of central is really a waste and meaningless?

Comment: I know, but I am not the manager of this nexus repository. And I forgot to tell that I am behind a NTLMv2 proxy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not even the manager of this Nexus server you are out of luck. You can only work around it by using another Nexus server, maybe installed locally, that does access central as well as your corporate, locked-down instance.

However, most likely, you are not allowed to do that.. locking it down was the reason to have a static repo in the first place.

I would suggest to work with the Nexus administrator to add javadoc and sources to your static repo.

And btw. I have a little tool that can provision a repository called the Maven Repository Provisioner and it can include javadoc and sources. Check it out at https://github.com/simpligility/maven-repository-tools